# How many primes are in this set?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fermat-numbers

From an old number theory book:

Consider all numbers of the form
$$
x_n={2^n+1}, n=0,1,2,\dots
$$
How many of them are prime?
Mathematica gave $x_0=2,x_1=3,x_2=5,x_4=17,x_8=257, x_{16}=65537$ and is still running!

We know that if it finds a prime like that it will be of the form $x_{2^k}+1$. So we only need to search for index a power of two. Has this been answered yet?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: These are *Fermat numbers*.

Comment: Are there only six prime Fermat numbers?

Comment: @GeorgiosPapamichael it's an open problem

Comment: See [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219833/are-there-finitely-or-infinitely-many-fermat-primes-decidable).

Comment: Strictly speaking , $2$ is not a Fermat-number because such a number must have the form $2^{2^n}+1$ with non-negative integer $n$, so $5$ Fermat-primes are known and $2$ is an additional prime of the desired form.

Comment: The smallest possible further prime of the desired form is $$\large F_{33}=2^{2^{33}}+1$$ which is a huge number! If another Fermat-prime exists, it will be much larger than the largest current known prime.

Answer (score 2):

Those are called [Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number), and it is not known how many there are. Only the first 5 are known.